# Following stratergy pattern; give interface access to parent attributes/methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning strategy pattern and I would like to use parent class attributes in the dynamically assigned functions.

For example (you can guess the book):

```py
class Duck():
    def __init__(self, wingspan: int, quack_behavior, fly_behavior):
        self.wingspan = wingspan
        self.quack = quack_behavior.quack
        self.fly = fly_behavior.fly

    def quack(self):
        pass

    def fly(self):
        pass

class FlyWithWings():
    def fly(self):
        print("I'm flying with wings")
        print(f"speed of {self.wingspan*1.1}")

class Quack():
    def quack(self):
        print("Quack, quack!")

class MallardDuck(Duck):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(wingspan=22, quack_behavior=Quack(), fly_behavior = FlyWithWings())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # welcome to the duck pond simulator
    first_duck = MallardDuck()
    first_duck.quack()
    first_duck.fly()
```

This fails with

```
AttributeError: 'FlyWithWings' object has no attribute 'wingspan'
```

A side note:
I'm violating the loose coupling principal because `FlyWithWings()` class depends on an attribute named `wingspan`. But I've run into problems with functions that needed a dozen attributes, which become hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

`FlyWithWings` is not aware of the specific `wingspan` of the object it's being used in. You can create a closure with the `wingspan` using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). This creates a function object with "frozen" arguments. So you can do:

```py
from functools import partial

class Duck():
    def __init__(self, wingspan: int, quack_behavior, fly_behavior):
        self.wingspan = wingspan
        self.quack = quack_behavior.quack
        self.fly = partial(fly_behavior.fly, wingspan)
```

And change `FlyWthWings` to:

```py
class FlyWithWings():
    def fly(self, wingspan):
        print("I'm flying with wings")
        print(f"speed of {wingspan*1.1}")
```

Comment: I have never heard of a closure. If another developer saw that solution, would they be satisfied or am I wrong to use that approach? I wonder if I'm wrong about sharing the wingspan attribute.